# What, at the bare minimum, is required for an HTTP request?

Tags: http

I'm trying to issue a GET command to my local server using `netcat` by doing the following:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: localhost" | nc localhost 80
```

Unfortunately, I get a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` response for this. What, at the very minimum, is required for a HTTP request?

Comment: Not sure, it works for me (Bash, Apache, Ubuntu) after I add `\n\n` to the back. But I think HTTP is sensitive to the nature of line endings, so maybe double-check that.

Comment: Echo has some issues in handling \r\n characters so same command using printf works but not with echo. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: related http://serverfault.com/questions/163511/what-is-the-mandatory-information-a-http-request-header-must-contain

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It must use CRLF line endings, and it must end in `\r\n\r\n`, i.e. a blank line. This is what I use:

```
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' |
  nc www.example.com 80
```

Additionally, I prefer `printf` over `echo`, and I add an extra header to have the server close the connection, but those aren’t needed.

Comment: And do remember that the newline in standard HTTP is always `\r\n`.

Comment: Nice, for my purposes, all I needed to do was `printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost 80\r\n\r\n' | nc localhost 80`. Thanks!

Comment: Host should be just `localhost` not `localhost 80`

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay `Host` format is defined as `Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ] ; Section 3.2.2` so it should be either `localhost` or `localhost:80`.

Answer (score 94):

if the request is: `"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"` then the response contains header as well as body, and the connection closes after the response.

if the request is:`"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host:port\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"`
then the response contains header as well as body, and the connection closes after the response.

if the request is:`"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host:port\r\n\r\n"` then the response contains header as well as body, and the connection will not close even after the response.

if your request is: `"GET /\r\n\r\n"` then the response contains no header and only body, and the connection closes after the response.

if your request is: `"HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"` then the response contains only header and no body, and the connection closes after the response.

if the request is: `"HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host:port\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"` then the response contains only header and no body, and the connection closes after the response.

if the request is: `"HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host:port\r\n\r\n"` then the response contains only header and no body, and the connection will not close after the response.

Comment: is it specific to a particular http server or is it mandated by http rfcs?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian
For HTTP 1.1 connections: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-8 ,
For HTTP 1.1 Host: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.23 ,
For HTTP 1.0 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945 ,
For HTTP 0.9 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html ,
HTTP Persistent connection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Persistent_connections (for persistent connections explanation, i am giving wikipedia link, as it has better explanation)

Comment: RFC 2616 is obsolete. Please don't cite it anymore except for historical purposes.

Comment: In the light of @JulianReschke's comment, here I am giving another link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/#rfc723x , for HTTP specification. Please find the links under "RFC 723X" on that page to read about latest RFC for HTTP specification.

Comment: Is "GET /\r\n\r\n" http/1.1 compliant?

Comment: @Kenneth "GET /\r\n\r\n" is HTTP/0.9 request. HTTP/1.1 servers conventionally provide backward compatibility.

Comment: it is automatically adding amp; on the URL used by http check request each time when i save the configuration. did anyone know the reason? `/jsonp/FreeForm?&amp;maxrecords=10&amp;format=XML&amp;`

Comment: @T.Anand Your Query String is getting URL-Form-Encoded. This depends on your program.

Comment: @AbhishekOza, i am giving the simple REST request URL on the http health check, so it keeps on adding amp; whenever i am saving the configuration, if i missed to remove the amp; from the URL then the Test getting failed, is there any way to look at pfsense HAProxy, Original URL - `/jsonp/FreeForm?&maxrecords=10&format=XML`, after i saved the configuration it is getting changed to `/jsonp/FreeForm?&amp;maxrecords=10&amp;format=XML&amp;`

Answer (score 13):

See [Wiki: HTTP Client Request (Example)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Client_request).

Note the following:

> > A client request (consisting in this case of the request line and only one header) is followed by a blank line, so that **the request ends with a double newline, each in the form of a carriage return followed by a line feed**. The "Host" header distinguishes between various DNS names sharing a single IP address, allowing name-based virtual hosting. While **optional in HTTP/1.0, it is mandatory in HTTP/1.1**.

The absolute minimum (if removing the Host is allowed ;-) is then `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`.

Happy coding

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thank you. (also the one that actually answers what's wrong with the HTTP/1.1 request above)

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get a response from my Apache server with *only* the requested document, no response header, with just

```
GET /\r\n
```

If you want response headers, including the status code, you need one of the other answers here though.

Comment: Interesting. This uses the original [HTTP/0.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) protocol from the early 90s. I'm very impressed Apache still responds to it.

Comment: Nginx also still supports this. From what I've seen, whenever someone develops a new HTTP server, they just copy all the kludges of other existing implementations, and this is why these things persist over decades.

Answer (score 7):

The fact of the `400 Bad Request` error itself does not imply that your request violates HTTP.  The server very well could be giving this response for another reason.

As far as I know the absolute minimum valid HTTP request is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: Actually, the absolute minimum is "GET /\r\n".  If no version is specified, the server is supposed to assume HTTP/0.9.  In HTTP/0.9, request headers aren't allowed, so you don't need the blank line to terminate them.  I wouldn't expect this to be supported everywhere, however, as HTTP/0.9 clients are *very* rare in reality, so servers may well not be tested with them.

Comment: HTTP/1.0 accepts no headers, HTTP/1.1 has a mandatory header: Host.

Answer (score 6):

Please, please, please, do not implement your own HTTP client without first reading the relevant specs. Please read and make sure that you've fully understood at least [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).  (And if you're ambitious, RFC 7230 through 7235).

While HTTP looks like an easy protocol, there are actually a number of subtle points about it.  Anyone who has written an HTTP server will tell you about the workarounds he had to implement in order to deal with incorrect but widely deployed clients.  Unless you're into reading specifications, please use a well-established client library; [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) is a good choice, but I'm sure there are others.

If you're going to implement your own:

- do not use HTTP/0.9;
- HTTP/1.0 requires the query line and the empty line;
- in HTTP/1.1, the `Host:` header is compulsory in addition to the above.

Omitting the `Host:` header in HTTP/1.1 is the most common cause of 400 errors.

Comment: In 2019 it seems that HTTP/1.0 has finally vanished and that you only need to support HTTP/1.1 (plus HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 if you wish).

Answer (score 0):

You should add an empty line: `\r\n\r\n`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Client_request

Answer (score 0):

The really REALLY BARE minimum, is not using netcat, but using bash itself:

```
user@localhost:~$ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/80
user@localhost:~$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" >&3
user@localhost:~$ cat <&3
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.6
Date: Mon, 13 Oct 2014 17:55:55 GMT
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 514

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><html>
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
<body>
<h2>Directory listing for /</h2>
<hr>
<ul>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
user@localhost:~$
```

Comment: Actually this is an invalid HTTP/1.1 request. 1. It should be using CRLF for line termination. 2. It should include `Host` header.

Comment: Webserver responded with 200 OK not with 400 Bad request.

Comment: It does not mean request was compliant with HTTP/1.1. Web servers in production are known to accept requests that are not 100% compliant with the HTTP/1.1. Reasons might vary but you should never rely on server understanding what you want if you send an invalid request. For instance, missing `Host` header is a very common reason for 400 because server simply cannot know what you want without it (Apache uses it for routing, for instance).

Comment: Yes, apache's vhost routing does that, but my example was requesting simplehttpserver localhost.

Comment: Some good soul zeroing me on this answer. I really don't get why I got negative score here. I've answered strictly.

Comment: FWIW, by minimum I meant the minimum actual request, not the code to produce such a request.

Comment: does not work with tomcat, but works if you use GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP 1.1, the minimum seems to be

```
const std::string host = "example.com";
std::stringstream http;
http << "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n";
http << "Host: " << host << "\r\n";
http << "Connection: close\r\n";
//end
http << "\r\n";
```

Without the 'Host' header a HTTP 400 Bad Request is returned (testing on a Apache server)
Without 'Connection: close' , the connection will not close (so, no response)