# SSL Socket Forcibly Closed - Python & IoT

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I have an IoT device that successfully communicates with the Google APIs.  I'm trying to get it to communicate with a new server, but with no luck.  On the IoT side, I would get a NULL response after about 7 or 8 seconds.  I think I understand this to mean the socket was closed but am not sure why.

I have a simple python script running under Windows that seems to explain more.  It appears that Windows is closing the socket.  Maybe this is a clue as to why my IoT is also failing.  (The socket firmware is 3rd party and I don't have an understanding of what's inside.)

Here is the script:

```
import socket
import ssl

# Host and port
host = '<deleted>'
port = 443  # HTTPS port

# Create a TCP socket
tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("\r\nsocket created", host, "\r\n")

# Wrap the TCP socket with SSL
ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(tcp_socket, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)

print("TCP converted to SSL socket", "\r\n")

# Connect to the server
ssl_socket.connect((host, port))

print("connection established", host, port, "\r\n")

print("execute send command:", "ssl_socket.send(b\"GET https://<deleted>\")")

ssl_socket.send(b"GET https://<deleted>")

print("\r\n\r\nresponse:")

response = ssl_socket.recv(4096)
print(response.decode())

ssl_socket.close()
```

And here is the output I get when running under Windows:

```
C:\Python37>python server.py

socket created <deleted>

TCP converted to SSL socket

connection established <hidden> 443

execute send command: ssl_socket.send(b"GET https://<deleted>")


response:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 29, in <module>
    response = ssl_socket.recv(4096)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1034, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 910, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

C:\Python37>
```

One thing I'm totally lost on is WRT certificates.  I've been told by the server engineers that I'm using the correct certificate and it appears to be installed properly in my IoT.  Is it possible the socket is being closed because the certificate isn't accepted?  I'm guessing not since the socket is opened successfully, so it must be something else.

One last thing...  The server has a sandbox that I use in a browser.  I can successfully communicate with the server using the same Windows machine that I'm running python on.

I have both the company responsible for the IoT socket stack and the company with the server looking into this (for about 6 weeks now).  I'm hoping someone can give me suggestions on how to resolve this.

Thanks for your time reading my long post.

Dave

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the Google servers are forgiving of incorrect HTTP but the new server is not. You should take care to send 100% compliant HTTP when debugging. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6686261/238704 and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/9233316/238704

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It's SSL so I can't capture a packet in the clear with WireShark.  The sandbox shows the json data but not the raw packet.  If I take the https command I'm using and put it in a browser, it takes me to the sandbox page.  Not sure that's a sign of anything wrong with the format of the command.  Also, the server engineers haven't seen anything wrong with what I'm doing.  But I'm probably the only person in the world trying to use their API in an IoT environment.  I believe they are learning in this environment too, and probably not a high priority.  Thanks!

Comment: If you upgrade to python3.8 or higher you can take advantage of SSLKEYLOGFILE support to allow Wireshark to decrypt the HTTPS stream.

Comment: Thanks PJKP.  I'm confused.  I can communicate with the server only using the web page sandbox.  How does python fit into that?  My IoT is over WiFi.  I tried capturing *any* packets (even encrypted) from my IoT through a WiFi modem to a smart switch with port mirroring and the mirrored port going to WireShark.  So far I've not been able to make that work.  :-(

Comment: Your GET request is invalid.

Comment: Maybe.  I'm an IoT guy, not a web guy.  Lots of things are invalid, but whether or not that is true doesn't get me to a solution.

Comment: Yes it does. All you have to do it’s what you should have done in the first place: look up the correct format and use it.

Comment: Thanks user207421.  I'm using the format that the server engineers have in their example python script.  I will ask them to validate.