# Accessing Docker daemon with Rust doesn't work

Tags: sockets, unix, docker, rust, daemon

I'd like to send a request to my Docker daemon with Rust but it doesn't work:

```
use std::os::unix::net::UnixStream;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut stream = UnixStream::connect("/var/run/docker.sock").unwrap();
    stream.write_all(b"GET /containers/json HTTP/1.1\r\n").unwrap();
    let mut response = String::new();
    stream.read_to_string(&mut response).unwrap();
    println!("{}", response);
}
```

I get no response, no error message. The program doesn't terminate.

Comment: Try ...`HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6686261/155423

Comment: My issue is : I get no response. That's it. No error message.
The program doesn't terminate.

Comment: And what happens when you make the suggested change?

Comment: No it's not the solution. Your previous link helped me. Thx.

Comment: I forgot : thank you for the kindness.

Comment: You are quite welcome.