# HTTP: leading blank line in header - a valid http request header?

Tags: apache, http, nginx, https, http-headers

Just wondering, is this a valid http request, please make a note of leading blank line(s) "\r\n" before the actually request headers.

```
\r\n\r\nGET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

Although it works with all the servers (apache, lighttpd, nginx), RFC doesn't mandate anything about leading blank lines and leave it to the implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the standard says each new line should end with `\r\n` and each request should end with `\r\n\r\n`

[What, at the bare minimum, is required for an HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686261/what-at-the-bare-minimum-is-required-for-an-http-request)

But most servers will handle leading newlines of most types

```
printf '\rGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' |
  nc www.example.com 80
printf '\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' |
  nc www.example.com 80
printf '\r\r\nGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' |
  nc www.example.com 80
printf '\n\rGET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' |
  nc www.example.com 80
```

About being valid or not, lot of the stuff on net is 100% compliant with RFC standards. You can also see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

So a space would create a problem at start but many of the servers would remove leading blank new lines