# Can't fetch desired content using socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the visible content from [here](http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt) using `socket` but unfortunately I'm getting an error when I execute my script. As I'm very new to code using `socket`, I can't understand as to where I'm going wrong.

My code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('data.pr4e.org')
s.connect((host_ip,80))
cmd = "GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n".encode()
s.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if (len(data) <1 ):
        break
    print(data.decode())
s.close()
```

Error I'm getting:

```
400 Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Comment: This error comes from the server. Your script is correctly reading the response.

Comment: Might as well just use the requests library....

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6686261/238704) is a relevant SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to obtain the desired result by adding `\r\n\r\n` to the end of the request command, rather than the original `\n\n`:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostbyname('data.pr4e.org'), 80))
s.sendall("GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode())
print(s.recv(1024))
```

Output:

```
...
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nBut soft what light through yonder window breaks\nIt is the east and Juliet is the sun\nArise fair sun and kill the envious moon\nWho is already sick and pale with grief\n'
```

Comment: Just use the `requests` library, then you won’t also hit a host of other problems that `requests` has already solved.

Comment: @barny I do agree, however, the OP is specifically trying to use `socket`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here:

1. It is uncommon to include `http://data.pr4e.org` after `GET` (see [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3)) unless talking to a proxy.  You will usually write `GET /romeo.txt` and provide the hostname in a [separate `Host: data.pr4e.org` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4).  Servers are required to support the form you used, but they might violate the standard and choke on it.  This is especially likely if you claim to be using HTTP/1.0, which is stricter and [forbids this form unless talking to a proxy](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-5.1.2).
2. Nobody uses HTTP/1.0 any more.  All modern browsers and other HTTP clients use HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.  Some servers will support HTTP/1.0, but it's not mandatory.  Note that HTTP/1.1 [makes the `Host:` header mandatory](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#appendix-A.1.1), even when you put the full URL after `GET`.
3. HTTP/1.0 uses `\r\n` ("CRLF") as a newline (see [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-11)), so `\n` may not always be understood.  Again, some servers will handle it correctly, but it is non-conforming.  The use of CRLF has been [carried over to HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3).
4. `print(data.decode())` will add an extra newline at the end of `data`.  This could become an issue if TCP fragments a large HTTP response so that `recv()` returns multiple nonempty strings.  Use `print(data.decode(), end='')` instead.

Comment: This is all perfectly valid critique of the question, but that doesn’t make it an answer.

Comment: @barny: The `\r\n` issue is the cause of OP's particular error in this case, so I don't see how this is "not an answer" at all.